# Client side date validation in SharePoint List form using jquery

Tags: jquery, list-form, validation

I want a validation for no past dates i.e something like

```
StartDate>=Today
```

Is this possible can anyone help? Thanks...

Comment: @RobWindsor, the first hit on that query is already pointing to this question. So your comment causes and endless loop, human stack overflow :D  ⁽ᶦ ᵈᵒ ʰᵃᵛᵉ ᵃ ˢᵉʳᶦᵒᵘˢ ᵖᵒᶦᶰᵗ ᵗʰᵒᵘᵍʰ⁾

Answer (score 2):

```
var startDateStr = $("#startdate").val();
var startDateArr = startDateStr.split("/");
var startDate = new Date(startDateArr[2], startDateArr[0], startDateArr[1]);
var todayDate = new Date();

if (startDate >= todayDate) {
   $("<div class=\"message-warning\">Your Message!</div>")
    .insertAfter("#enddate");
};
```

Comment: Anuja, using this, can i compare two date time fields?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MebwN/48/)

If the result is in negative return false in PreSaveAction() check [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/86fe14fc-f353-4521-bf88-fd7fcabaa768/using-presaveaction-in-newformaspx-in-sharepoint-list)